# Your database version: 6030000. Required version: 6000000. helm cetic/zabbix

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, zabbix

### Problem description:

I was following the instruction of https://github.com/cetic/helm-zabbix/tree/3.1.1#installation to install zabbix with helm in k8s with below commands but failed to visit the web page of zabbix with the error shown in the below pic

```
helm repo add cetic https://cetic.github.io/helm-charts

helm repo update

helm show values cetic/zabbix > /Users/xiaojueguan/code/AMD/workplace/docs/infra/zabbix/zabbix_values.yaml

helm upgrade --install zabbix cetic/zabbix \
 --dependency-update \
 --create-namespace \
 -f /Users/xiaojueguan/code/AMD/workplace/docs/infra/zabbix/zabbix_values.yaml -n monitoring --debug

kubectl get pods -n monitoring
```

[image]

### Things I tried

login into the postgresql server and set the mandatory db version to 6000000 but failed

```
k get secrets  zabbixdb-pguser-zabbix --template={{.data.password}} | base64 -D
psql -h 10.244.0.151 -U zabbix
use zabbix
update dbversion set mandatory=6030000
flush privileges
```

change the version of postgresql from 14.4 to 13.8 but no luck

### Add some update

In the logic of below, we can see that version is found in the db and the other is defined in the code. As the code side we can not change, maybe we can work on the db side.

1. maybe the field can be changed
2. maybe we need use postgresq with certain version

https://github1s.com/zabbix/zabbix/blob/release/6.2/ui/include/classes/db/DbBackend.php#L117-L139

```php
    /**
     * Check if connected database version matches with frontend version.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function checkDbVersion() {
        if (!$this->checkDbVersionTable()) {
            return false;
        }

        $version = DBfetch(DBselect('SELECT dv.mandatory FROM dbversion dv'));

        if ($version['mandatory'] != ZABBIX_DB_VERSION) {
            $this->setError(_s('The Zabbix database version does not match current requirements. Your database version: %1$s. Required version: %2$s. Please contact your system administrator.',
                $version['mandatory'], ZABBIX_DB_VERSION
            ));

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

https://github1s.com/zabbix/zabbix/blob/release/6.2/ui/include/defines.inc.php#L25

```
define('ZABBIX_DB_VERSION',     6020000);
```

Comment: It looks like the schema was created by a zabbix of a newer version than the zabbix trying to use the schema.